I am writing my OS. Kernel is in panic state after implementing hardware interrupt and PIC. where am i wrong?
I am trying to enable hardware interrupts and currently implementing PIC, But kernel is going into panic state.
I am using nasm and C to write my kernel. Please help.
When i call enable_interrupts() in kernel.c, it leads to kernel in panic state.p
this is my kernel. asm code snippet
; Remap the master PIC
    mov al, 00010001b
    out 0x20, al           ; Send the command to the master PIC 

    mov al, 0x20           ; Interrupt 0x20 is the starting point of the master PIC interrupt
    out 0x21, al           ; Send the command to the master PIC

    mov al, 00000001b      ; Put the master PIC in 8086 mode
    out 0x21, al           ; Send the command to the master PIC

    
;End of PIC remapping

    
    call kernel_main

this is my kernel.c main function
void kernel_main() {
    terminal_initialize();
    print("Hello World \n This is my os \n");
    
    print("Initializing IDT...\n");
    idt_init();
    print("IDT initialized.\n");

    print("Enabling interrupts...\n");
    enable_interrupts();
    print("Interrupts enabled.\n");

    print("Kernel initialization complete.\n");
}


This is my idt.asm
section .asm

extern int21h_handler
extern no_interrupt_handler

global idt_load
global int21h
global enable_interrupts
global disable_interrupts
global no_interrupt


enable_interrupts:
    sti
    ret

disable_interrupts:
    cli
    ret

idt_load:
    push ebp
    mov ebp , esp

    mov eax , [ebp + 8]
    lidt [eax]

    pop ebp
    ret 

int21h:
    cli
    pushad      ; Pushes the content of all the GPRs onto the stack
    call int21h_handler
    popad       ; Pops the content of all the GPRs off the stack
    sti
    iret        ; pops 5 things off the stack: CS, EIP, EFLAGS, SS, and ESP 


no_interrupt:
    cli
    pushad
    call no_interrupt_handler
    popad
    sti
    iret

This is my idt.c
#include "idt.h"
#include "../config.h"
#include "../memory/memory.h"
#include "../kernel.h"
#include "../io/io.h"

// Define the variables here
struct idt_desc idt_descriptors[256];
struct idtr_desc idtr_descriptor;

extern void idt_load(struct idtr_desc* ptr);
extern void int21h();
extern void no_interrupt();

void no_interrupt_handler() {
    print("Unhandled interrupt\n");
    outb(0x20, 0x20);
}

void int21h_handler() {
    print("Keyboard pressed\n");
    outb(0x20, 0x20);
 // Send EOI to master PIC
}
void idt_zero(){
    print("Divide by zero error\n");
}

void idt_set(int interrupt_no , void* addr){
    struct idt_desc* desc = &idt_descriptors[interrupt_no];
    desc->offset_1 = (uint32_t) addr & 0x0000FFFF;
    desc->selector = KERNEL_CODE_SEGMENT;
    desc->zero = 0x00;
    desc->type_attr = 0x8E;
    desc->offset_2 = (uint32_t) addr >> 16;
} 

void idt_init(){
    memset(idt_descriptors , 0 , sizeof(idt_descriptors));
    idtr_descriptor.limit = sizeof(idt_descriptors) - 1;
    idtr_descriptor.base = (uint32_t)idt_descriptors; 

    for (int i = 0; i < PIZZAOS_TOTAL_INTERRUPTS; i++){
        idt_set(i , no_interrupt);
    }
    idt_set(0 , idt_zero);
    idt_set(0x21 , int21h);

    
// Load the idt
    idt_load(&idtr_descriptor);
}


this is my idt.h
#ifndef IDT_H
#define IDT_H

#include <stdint.h>

struct idt_desc
{
    uint16_t offset_1; // Offset bits 0 - 15
    uint16_t selector;  // Selector thats in our GDT
    uint8_t zero;       // Does nothing, unused set to zero
    uint8_t type_attr;  // Descriptor type and attributes
    uint16_t offset_2;  // Offset bits 16-31
} __attribute__((packed));

struct idtr_desc
{
    uint16_t limit;      // Size of descriptor table -1
    uint32_t base;        // Base address of the start of the interrupt descriptor table
} __attribute__((packed));

// Change these to extern declarations
extern struct idt_desc idt[256];
extern struct idtr_desc idtr;

void idt_init();
void enable_interrupts();
void disable_interrupts();  



void idt_set(int interrupt_no , void*  address );

#endif

I am new to os dev, trying to follow along osdev but Just cant figure out whats wrong here.
I tried setting master and Slave PIC but that doesnt seem to solve my issue.
My project is on Github in the branch bug---PIC

Use a debugger. Its almost impossible finding bugs in code this low-level without the use of a good debugger.

I answered this over on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/osdev/comments/1fw49gb/i_need_help_kernel_in_panic_state/

thanks a lot @MichaelPetch
